# How to disable onscreen keyboard on startup of view in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, textformfield

I started out writing a Flutter app to remotely control some radio stream. I ran into a problem when adding a `TextFormField` to display the stream's current volume setting. (The reason why I opted for a `TextFormField` instead of simply `Text` is that I wanted to use the field for both showing the current setting and letting the user change the current value in one place.)

The problem is the following: When I added the `TextFormField` (located inside the green bar in the screen shot below, after the text `Vol:`), I realized that whenever I started this view/page, **the onboard keyboard always showed up by default when entering the page**.

Instead, I would like the keyboard to only show up when the user clicks inside the `TextFormField`.

The code for the `TextFormField` looks as follows:

```
TextFormField(
  onFieldSubmitted: (value){
    print("The value entered is : $value");
  },
  // Define keyboard type
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  // Make sure user doesn't enter letters or punctuation
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
  validator: (val){
    return null; 
  },
  autofocus: true,
  controller: volTextEditingController,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 16,
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
  maxLines: 1,
)
```

So, I was wondering whether someone knows how to prevent the keyboard from appearing on startup of the shown view/page. Thanks in advance! The full code, if needed, is available on [GitGub](https://github.com/Bick95/radio_remote/blob/master/lib/views/radio_control.dart#L124).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that this problem was caused by the setting `autofocus: true`. So, removing this solves the issue.